# URL extraction from Domain sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to extract the domain name from the urls from my db.  What i tried is getting me just 70% closer to the output that i want, I'm unable to format few urls that are in my table. Can someone suggest me a better technique to deal such situations?

| website_addr |
| --- |
| abcd |
| http://www.google.com |
| https://www.yahoo.com |
| [www.aol.com](http://www.aol.com) |
| www.ebay.com,www.ebay.com |
| https://www.ebix.com/ |
| xavier.com |
| www.rubix.com |
| https://rend-auv.com |

Output that i'm currently getting:

| website_addr | output |
| --- | --- |
| abcd | abcd |
| http://www.google.com | [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) |
| https://www.yahoo.com | [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com) |
| [www.aol.com](http://www.aol.com) | w.aol.com |
| www.ebay.com,www.ebay.com | www.ebay.com,www.ebay.com |
| www.rubix.com | w.rubix.com |
| https://www.ebix.com/ | [www.ebix.com](http://www.ebix.com) |
| xavier.com | xavier.com |
| https://rend-auv.com | rend-auv.com |

The output i expect

| website_addr | output |
| --- | --- |
| abcd | abcd |
| http://www.google.com | [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) |
| https://www.yahoo.com | [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com) |
| [www.aol.com](http://www.aol.com) | [www.aol.com](http://www.aol.com) |
| www.rubix.com | [www.rubix.com](http://www.rubix.com) |
| www.ebay.com,www.ebay.com | [www.ebay.com](http://www.ebay.com) |
| https://www.ebix.com/ | [www.ebix.com](http://www.ebix.com) |
| xavier.com | xavier.com |
| https://rend-auv.com | rend-auv.com |

what i tried.

```sql
substring(
substring(add_website_addr,charindex('://',add_website_addr)+3,len(add_website_addr)),
0,
case when charindex('/',substring(website_addr,charindex('://',website_addr)+3,len(website_addr)))>0  
then charindex('/',substring(website_addr,charindex('://',website_addr)+3,len(website_addr)))
when charindex('?',substring(website_addr,charindex('://',website_addr)+3,len(website_addr)))>0  
then charindex('?',substring(website_addr,charindex('://',website_addr)+3,len(website_addr)))
else
len(website_addr)
end
)
```

Comment: 1. Fix your design, don't store delimited data in your database. 2: (After you fix your design) Isn't this just a `REPLACE`?

Comment: thanks for you time but a replace isn't working since my table got a mix of urls like the samples i pulled out in the question.

Comment: Which is why i said *after* you fix your design. Then it's simply a `REPLACE`. (You are replacing `'https://'` and `'http://` with `''`)

Comment: I get you but unfortunately it cannot be altered at this point. The option limited to me is to cleanse the the url names without disturbing the schema

Comment: *"The option limited to me is to cleanse the the url names without disturbing the schema"* That sounds like fixing the design, if I am honest, considering you want to change `'www.ebay.com,www.ebay.com'` to `'www.ebay.com'`. What would happen if you had `'www.ebay.com,www.ebay.co.uk'`?

Comment: the domain names are fed according to their relevance. So the first name will be the most accurate one.

Answer (score -1):

You just want to remove the leading values of "http://" or "https://". Is that accurate? There are numerous ways. One simple example

```
declare @x table (url varchar(50));
insert @x (url) values 
('abcd'), ('http://www.google.com'), ('https://www.yahoo.com'), ('www.aol.com'); 


select *, 
case when left(url, 8) = 'https://' then stuff(url, 1, 8, '') 
     when left(url, 7) = 'http://'  then stuff(url, 1, 7, '') 
     else url 
end as z
from @x;
```

Comment: i also wanted to get rid of the extra ' / ' which is found after the com.

Comment: @lavanya_satheesh So make an effort. If (hint) the last character (hint - right) is "/', you can stuff (another hint) it.

Comment: Thank you Smore. I tried my part and i fixed it but i had to do it 2-3 parts. 1st i repaced all the http and https then i created a dupe table and removed the www , then i perfermed a replace to remove the extra backslash. I wish it could be done in one step instead of an ordeal